# How to write provider type of service and how to get values from that in config level in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Actually I want to set some dynamic values at my module configuration level,So only choice is provider .How to set scope values to provider and how to get those values from provider in configuration.I have basic idea to write a provider in angularjs .But I don't know how to read values from that one.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.provider('movie', function () {
  var version;
  return {
    setVersion: function (value) {
      version = value;
    },
    $get: function () {
      return {
          title: 'The Matrix' + ' ' + version
      }
    }
  }
});

app.config(function (movieProvider) {
  movieProvider.setVersion('Reloaded');
});
```

Please help some body to do this..

```
.config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
                $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')

                    .primaryPalette(primaryColor)
                    .accentPalette(secondaryColor);

            });
```

In above code I have to set primary and secondary colors from scope of the controller...

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain `version` data by using [**`angular.constant`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module) which you will set in factory as well in configuration level

**Constant**

```
angular.constant('configData',{
   version: ''
});
```

Provider will set value of constant, the variable will not be the part of factory.

**Provider**

```
app.provider('movie', function (configData) {
  return {
    setVersion: function (value) {
      configData.version = value;
    },
    $get: function () {
      return {
          title: 'The Matrix' + ' ' + configData.version
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: In my case ,I have to call rest api and get values from that and need to fill colors,these all things need to happen before page loading